# Default loss function contrib.learn DNNRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow

super quick question. What is the default loss function in Tensorflow's contrib.learn? I looked at the documentation and could not find anything. Just to clarify, I am asking if it is absolute difference, MAE, MSE, RMSE or any other. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538710/how-to-interpret-loss-function-in-tensorflow-dnnregressor-estimator-model), the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor` uses mean squared error as default loss. I have to admit though, that I couldn't find the source file for it. It would be interesting for me too.