# Predictive Maintenance - How to use Bayesian Optimization with objective function and Logistic Regression with Gradient Descent together?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, hyperparameters

I'm trying to reproduce the problem shown in [arimo.com](https://arimo.com/machine-learning/2016/manufacturing-downtime-cost-reduction-predictive-maintenance/)

This is an example how to build a preventive maintenance Machine Learning model for an Hard Drive failures. The section I really don't understand is how to use Bayesian Optimization with a custom objective function and Logistic Regression with Gradient Descent together. What are the hyper-parameters to be optimized? What is the flow of the problem?

> As described in our previous post, Bayesian Optimization [6] is used
>   to find the best hyperparameter values. The objective function to be
>   optimized in the hyperparameter tuning is the following score measured
>   on the validation set:
>
> S = alpha * fnr + (1 – alpha) * fpr
>
> where fpr and fnr are the False Positive and False Negative rates
>   obtained on the validation set. Our goal is to keep False Positive
>   rate low, therefore we use alpha = 0.2. Since the validation set is
>   highly unbalanced, we found out that standard scores like Precision,
>   F1-score, etc… do not work well. In fact, using this custom score is
>   crucial for the model to obtain a good performance generally.
>
> Note that we only use the above score when running Bayesian
>   Optimization. To train logistic regression models, we use Gradient
>   Descent with the usual ridge loss function.

My dataframe before features selection:

```
index   date    serial_number   model   capacity_bytes  failure     Read Error Rate     Reallocated Sectors Count   Power-On Hours (POH)    Temperature     Current Pending Sector Count    age     yesterday_temperature   yesterday_age   yesterday_reallocated_sectors_count     yesterday_read_error_rate   yesterday_current_pending_sector_count  yesterday_power_on_hours    tomorrow_failure
0   77947   2013-04-11  MJ0331YNG69A0A  Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630     3000592982016   0   0   0   4909    29  0   36348284.0  29.0    20799895.0  0.0     0.0     0.0     4885.0  0.0
1   79327   2013-04-11  MJ1311YNG7EWXA  Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630     3000592982016   0   0   0   8831    24  0   36829839.0  24.0    21280074.0  0.0     0.0     0.0     8807.0  0.0
2   79592   2013-04-11  MJ1311YNG2ZD9A  Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630     3000592982016   0   0   0   13732   26  0   36924206.0  26.0    21374176.0  0.0     0.0     0.0     13708.0     0.0
3   80715   2013-04-11  MJ1311YNG2ZDBA  Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630     3000592982016   0   0   0   12745   27  0   37313742.0  27.0    21762591.0  0.0     0.0     0.0     12721.0     0.0
4   79958   2013-04-11  MJ1323YNG1EK0C  Hitachi HDS5C3030ALA630     3000592982016   0   524289  0   13922   27  0   37050016.0  27.0    21499620.0  0.0     0.0     0.0     13898.0     0.0
```

Comment: Bayesian Optimization is independent of Logistic Regression internals. In fact, it doesn't care how exactly you compute the objective function - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41860817/712995